# Android - transparent GradientDrawable turns gray on emulator

Tags: java, android, view, drawable, android-drawable

[image: transparent turns gray][image: transparent turns gray]

I am using GradientDrawable for decoration.

The transparent is correct on the real devices, but it turns gray on some emulators *(It seems to be correct after a certain system version)*.

my code like

```java
... new GradientDrawable()
        .setCornerRadius(...)
        .setColors(...) //set multiple colors with transparent here
        .setOrientation(...)
...
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are You using the default "@android:color/transparent"?
the solution is on the hex code, sometimes the default is a "black transparent": #00000000,
this cause the gradient going gray.

Try to manually set the transparent to white: #00FFFFFF,
this should solve your problem